DateTime format not showing correctly on iPhone in ASP.NET web application
I have a razor pages web application that shows DateTimes throughout the application. Everything works great on a desktop browser at all media sizes (including mobile). But when I view the application on my iPhone (using Safari or Google Chrome) the DateTime formats do not show the same as they would on desktop.
For example, a DateTime value of 2024-06-15 11:25:54 PM on Desktop, will show as 2024-06-15 11:25:54 p.m on mobile.
This is my program.cs file:
// Early init of NLog to allow startup and exception logging, before host is built
var logger = NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings().GetCurrentClassLogger();

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables();

    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
    culture.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
    {
        ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
        ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
        LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
        FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
        DateSeparator = "-",
        TimeSeparator = ":"
    };

    builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
    {
        var supportedCultures = new[]
         {
        new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
    };
        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture, culture);
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    });

    builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

    // Authorization services...

    // Configuration services...

    // Other application services...

    // Identity services...

    // Logging configuration

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMiddleware<LogMiddleware>();
    app.UseMiddleware<OnboardingMiddleware>();

    app.MapRazorPages();

    // Static files will not load in any environment except Development without this.
    StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(app.Environment, app.Configuration);

    logger.Info($"Application starting in environment: {app.Environment.EnvironmentName}");
    app.Run();

} catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.Fatal(ex, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}

To fix the problem where AM and PM show as a.m and p.m, I modified the DateTimeFormat as follows:

    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
    culture.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
    {
        ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
        LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
        ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
        LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
        FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
        DateSeparator = "-",
        TimeSeparator = ":",
        AMDesignator = "AM",
        PMDesignator = "PM"
    };

This had no affect on how DateTimes were displayed on mobile. In short, it seems as though the DateTimeFormatInfo configuration has no effect when viewing the application from a mobile device. My application is deployed on IIS.
As an example, here is how I would display the DateTime in a Razor Page:
@foreach (Command command in Model.Commands.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateCreated))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span class="text-black text-opacity-75" style="font-size: 14px;">@command.DateCreated</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
}

When I start debugging using the Keyoti Extension (which allows you to access your web application from IOS devices) and load the page, everything works fine and I am served correct DateTime formats which have PM instead of p.m. This leads me to believe this is an issue with IIS and or my Windows Virtual Machine.
As a test I rendered the current CultureInfo using the following code:
<p>@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat).ToString()</p>

On desktop Google Chrome:
{
   "AMDesignator":"AM",
   "Calendar":{
      "MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999",
      "AlgorithmType":1,
      "CalendarType":1,
      "Eras":[
         1
      ],
      "TwoDigitYearMax":2029,
      "IsReadOnly":false
   },
   "DateSeparator":"-",
   "FirstDayOfWeek":0,
   "CalendarWeekRule":0,
   "FullDateTimePattern":"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
   "LongDatePattern":"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
   "LongTimePattern":"hh:mm:ss tt",
   "MonthDayPattern":"MMMM dd",
   "PMDesignator":"PM",
   "RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'",
   "ShortDatePattern":"yyyy-MM-dd",
   "ShortTimePattern":"hh:mm:ss tt",
   "SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",
   "TimeSeparator":":",
   "UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
   "YearMonthPattern":"yyyy MMMM",
   "AbbreviatedDayNames":[
      "Sun",
      "Mon",
      "Tue",
      "Wed",
      "Thu",
      "Fri",
      "Sat"
   ],
   "ShortestDayNames":[
      "Su",
      "Mo",
      "Tu",
      "We",
      "Th",
      "Fr",
      "Sa"
   ],
   "DayNames":[
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
   ],
   "AbbreviatedMonthNames":[
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
      ""
   ],
   "MonthNames":[
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
      ""
   ],
   "IsReadOnly":false,
   "NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar",
   "AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":[
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
      ""
   ],
   "MonthGenitiveNames":[
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
      ""
   ]
}

On mobile Google Chrome App & Safari:
{
   "AMDesignator":"a.m.",
   "Calendar":{
      "MinSupportedDateTime":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "MaxSupportedDateTime":"9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999",
      "AlgorithmType":1,
      "CalendarType":1,
      "Eras":[
         1
      ],
      "TwoDigitYearMax":2029,
      "IsReadOnly":true
   },
   "DateSeparator":"-",
   "FirstDayOfWeek":0,
   "CalendarWeekRule":0,
   "FullDateTimePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
   "LongDatePattern":"dddd, MMMM d, yyyy",
   "LongTimePattern":"h:mm:ss tt",
   "MonthDayPattern":"MMMM d",
   "PMDesignator":"p.m.",
   "RFC1123Pattern":"ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'",
   "ShortDatePattern":"yyyy-MM-dd",
   "ShortTimePattern":"h:mm tt",
   "SortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss",
   "TimeSeparator":":",
   "UniversalSortableDateTimePattern":"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'",
   "YearMonthPattern":"MMMM yyyy",
   "AbbreviatedDayNames":[
      "Sun.",
      "Mon.",
      "Tue.",
      "Wed.",
      "Thu.",
      "Fri.",
      "Sat."
   ],
   "ShortestDayNames":[
      "S",
      "M",
      "T",
      "W",
      "T",
      "F",
      "S"
   ],
   "DayNames":[
      "Sunday",
      "Monday",
      "Tuesday",
      "Wednesday",
      "Thursday",
      "Friday",
      "Saturday"
   ],
   "AbbreviatedMonthNames":[
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec",
      ""
   ],
   "MonthNames":[
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
      ""
   ],
   "IsReadOnly":true,
   "NativeCalendarName":"Gregorian Calendar",
   "AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames":[
      "Jan.",
      "Feb.",
      "Mar.",
      "Apr.",
      "May",
      "Jun.",
      "Jul.",
      "Aug.",
      "Sep.",
      "Oct.",
      "Nov.",
      "Dec.",
      ""
   ],
   "MonthGenitiveNames":[
      "January",
      "February",
      "March",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "August",
      "September",
      "October",
      "November",
      "December",
      ""
   ]
}

Additionally, if I go into Safari setting on IOS and change the language to English (UK) instead of just English, I am now served the correct DateTime using PM instead of p.m.

Please show the part where you actually render such a date.

@BenderBoy I have edited the post and added an example.

Unless you’re detecting mobile browsers server-side and specifically serve them different time formats, this has to be a front-end issue. Are you using and javascript libraries that could mess with dates?!

@BenderBoy There is no javascript interacting with the DateTimes, it is purely rendering the DateTime in a razor page. I have added more examples and new findings to the post that indicate the issue may have to do with the browser's CultureInfo somehow overriding the configuration in my Program.cs.

You could try below code which use the Moment.js file which will handle date formatting on the client side.
Models/Command.cs:
namespace DateTimeFormattingApp.Models
{
    public class Command
    {
        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    }
}

Services/CommandService.cs:
using DateTimeFormattingApp.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace DateTimeFormattingApp.Services
{
    public class CommandService
    {
        private static List<Command> commands = new List<Command>
        {
            new Command { DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-1) },
            new Command { DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) },
            new Command { DateCreated = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1) },
        };

        public List<Command> GetCommands()
        {
            return commands.OrderByDescending(c => c.DateCreated).ToList();
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml:
@page
@model DateTimeFormattingApp.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>Commands</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var command in Model.Commands)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="text-black text-opacity-75" style="font-size: 14px;" data-date="@command.DateCreated.ToString("o")"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        document.querySelectorAll("[data-date]").forEach(function (element) {
            var date = element.getAttribute("data-date");
            var formattedDate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss A");
            element.textContent = formattedDate;
        });
    });
</script>

Index.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using DateTimeFormattingApp.Models;
using DateTimeFormattingApp.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DateTimeFormattingApp.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly CommandService _commandService;

        public IndexModel(CommandService commandService)
        {
            _commandService = commandService;
        }

        public List<Command> Commands { get; set; }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            Commands = _commandService.GetCommands();
        }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using DateTimeFormattingApp.Services;



var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-CA");
culture.DateTimeFormat = new DateTimeFormatInfo
{
    ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd",
    LongDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
    ShortTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
    LongTimePattern = "hh:mm:ss tt",
    FullDateTimePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt",
    DateSeparator = "-",
    TimeSeparator = ":",
    AMDesignator = "AM",
    PMDesignator = "PM"
};


builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
    {
        culture,
    };
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture, culture);
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<CommandService>();

var app = builder.Build();



// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

var localizationOptions = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value;
app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

